# Does MOD(primarykey) on an InnoDB partitioned table cause fragmentation

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, modulus

I'm exporting a largeish table (1.5 billion rows) between servers. This is the table format.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `partitionedtable` (
  `domainid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `instanceid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `urlid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `adjrankid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domainid`,`instanceid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (MOD(domainid,8192))
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB
 ...
 PARTITION p8191 VALUES LESS THAN (8192) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

The data was exported to the new server in PK order and resulted in 8192 text files... which equated to around 200K records per file.

I'm simply iterating from 0 to 8191 importing the files into the new table.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/backup/rc/$i.tsv INTO TABLE partitionedtable PARTITION (p$i)
```

I'm thinking that each of these should only take a second to import, however they take around 6 seconds.

The spec of the server can be seen here.
http://www.ovh.co.uk/dedicated_servers/sp_32g.xml

There isn't much else going on in the server that'd bottleneck the process.

Could it be that partitioning by MOD() causes fragmentation? I was under the impression that there wouldnt be any fragmentation as each partition would be considered a separate table, and since data is inserted in PK order there'd be no fragmentation.

- Added - probably useful... these settings were applied at the start of the batch.

  SET autocommit=0; 
  SET foreign_key_checks=0; 
  SET sql_log_bin=0; 
  SET unique_checks=0;

A COMMIT is applied after every file.

The thread seems to spend the majority of its time in a **System lock** state, during LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: Does not it involve copying data from file to database table file?

Comment: sure, but having the files sitting in /dev/shm doesn't seem to make any difference, which should eliminate one half of any IO slowness. The files work out to being only 8MB in size, pretty small.

Comment: Check CPU load per core. It takes 1 core per partition, so writing data into 8192 partitions may be quite painful. Compare to loading into a table with 6-8 HASH partitions

Comment: CPU load is OK. It's well below the limit. I'm loading them in 1 at a time so don't see an issue with # partitions/concurrency.

Comment: Can you post output from `SHOW PROFILE`?

Comment: Sure, here it is. It ran a touch faster. http://pastebin.com/qVT8mrxv

Answer (score 0):

When I set up the server I mistakenly thought the open files limit was higher, though in reality it's sitting at 1024.

I've upped it to 16000 and rebooted the server, and it's running slightly quicker @ 3 seconds (I was assuming the file opening/closing was causing the system lock status).

I also purged the bin logs.

Still seems a bit slow though.